# Hibernate Search save entity to Elastic search

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I trye to use Hibernate Search with elastic search, for full text search.
Simple entitys work correctly but with one i have a troube.
When i setup annotation @FullTextField on a data column i got an error when application starting:

> "Hibernate ORM mapping:
> type 'ru.search.entities.TestEntity':
> path '.data':
> failures:
> - HSEARCH000135: No default value bridge implementation for type 'java.lang.Object'. Use a custom bridge."

This my entity:

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index = "test")
@Table(name = "test")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = Jsonb.class)
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID Id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, Object> data;
//constructor
//getters 
//setters
}
```

Without @FullTextField annotation entity puts correctly in postgres and elastic. Elastic of course do not contain data column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you annotate a `Map` with `@FullTextField` (or any `@*Field` annotation), Hibernate Search will index the values. In you case, values are of type `Object`. Hibernate Search doesn't know how to index an `Object`.

I suspect you want to index arbitrary JSON data. If that's the case, I believe there's a solution for you right in the documentation examples:

- Read [this section first](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-field-bridge) to get some context on what property bridges are and how you can use them.
- Then you can find a (more complicated) example that does almost exactly what you want [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-index-field-dsl-dynamic).

If that's not what you need, I suggest exploring the documentation:

- You can find a list of supported property types [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-supported-types)
- You can find help on mapping other property types [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-custom-types)